# Clojure's -main function not fully executed

Tags: clojure

Is this an expected behaviour, or it's a problem with my Clojure installations (I'm checking it on Windows and Linux)?

I have a simple project, created with `lein new app testfor`. Here's the code of `src/testfor/core.clj`:

```
(ns testfor.core
    (:gen-class))

(defn -main [& args]
    (println "hello")
    (for [x [1 2 3]]
        (println x)))
```

When I run `lein repl` and invoke `(-main)` from the REPL, the output is this:

```
testfor.core=> (-main)
hello
1
2
3
```

But then I run the application with `lein run`, or `lein uberjar` and run the generated JAR file, the output is this:

```
$ lein run
hello
```

So, it somehow doesn't run the `for` loop.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this is because `for` returns a lazy-sequence of elements - https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/for

In the example when you call the `-main` function from the repl, in this case the last expression in the function is returned from the function call (just like any other function call). The REPL sees the lazy-seq and attempts to print it, which requires realising the seq, which will evaluate the `println` statements.

In the example when you Leiningen calls the main method, it is like calling a main method on a Java class which has a void return type `public static void main`. Clojure will see it as lazy and nothing tries to realise the seq so the `println` expressions are never evaluated.

Answer (score 5):

`for` is not a for loop like in Java. It creates a lazy sequence that depends on the different options you specify. See [for](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/for) documentation.

The important point in your case is the *lazy* word.
The repl will actually force the realisation of the lazy sequence, but when running with `lein`, this is not the case. In order to do what you want you need to force with either `dorun` or `doall` :

```
(defn -main [& args]
  (println "hello")
  (dorun (for [x [1 2 3]]
           (println x))))


cuvier:tgo$ lein run
hello
1
2
3
```